# Nexus 5x came with preinstalled android 7.0.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x

I've recently bought Nexus 5x from amazon and it came with android 7.0.0, but official specification says that it comes with android 6. So question: does it mean something wrong with my device (used, refurbished etc)?

Answer (score 1):

It's most definitely refurbished.  Android 7 doesn't come preinstalled on the Nexus 5X brand new.

Comment: I did mean 5x sorry.

Comment: Yes, I've think about it, but I need to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for testing whether an Android phone is refurbished.
[How to tell if your phone is refurbished](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21101/how-to-tell-if-your-phone-is-refurbished) gives a list that you can try, to begin with. It is not guaranteed to work, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Ok, I will test it and let you know.